# Marketing Cloud DE Time of Update Field

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Has anybody been able to implement a data extension field that marks the time of the last update of a row? We would like to make note of when a subscriber flag is updated for tracking purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this data getting updated?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about this use case. Such things as: How is the data being imported/updated? Where is this being stored? Would you require this to include any UI updates, or only data import updates? Will this be updated manually or via API/Bulk import? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ability to implicitly set a field to store the *last updated* timestamp for a DE row. You will need to include this information (timestamp with current time) when updating that specific record.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks. That looks like it will have to be the method used. We're using a query to make the update from all subscribers unsubscribe to our data extension, so will add to the query.